Can I use IntraWeb in the Lazarus IDE?
I am currently exploring web development options in the Lazarus IDE.
I know TMS WEB Core is available for Lazarus.
I am wondering if IntraWeb is compatible with the Lazarus IDE. I have used IntraWeb with RAD Studio (Delphi) before, but I am not sure if there is any support for it in the Lazarus environment.
I did not find anything on the IntraWeb website.
I found this document from 2006, which says:

An environment such as Intraweb is not yet available for Lazarus or FPC.

This is from 2006, though. Is it still the case in 2024? Is it possible to use IntraWeb in the Lazarus IDE? If so, how?

I found this post from 2023 on the Atozed website stating that it works, but is not finished yet: https://www.atozed.com/forums/archive/index.php?thread-3534.html

Support for Lazarus is definitely in the works. Here are some online posts from AToZed mentioning it recently:
November 22, 2023
https://www.atozed.com/2023/11/15-5-0-h/


Major refactoring targeting compatibility with FreePascal compiler. 100% of IntraWeb runtime code is now compatible with FreePascal/Lazarus and we are getting close to the first release supporting Lazarus


December 15th, 2023
https://www.atozed.com/forums/thread-3714.html

Runtime support for Lazarus is 100% ready.
Design time support is coming together nicely

...

The first version will be Windows only, meaning that you can build in Lazarus but the targets will need to be either Win32 or Win64.
But, the Linux version will be next on our roadmap. The hard work is already done. Most core stuff works both in Windows and Linux (as long as we use FPC), except the Http.sys application type.

December 23rd, 2023
https://www.atozed.com/forums/thread-3732.html

It's been a wonderful year. So many things in our list are done now. I won't spend any time going back to our work items and logs to list that to you, but making IntraWeb compatible with Lazarus (yes, it is a few DAYS away) and also releasing and Indy TLS 1.3 compatible version (That performs 25% better, yay!) was awesome! Really rewarding....

May 9, 2024
https://www.atozed.com/2024/05/whats-new-in-intraweb-15/


Lazarus/Free Pascal support both Win32 and Win64 (to be released next)


I don't know the specific details about how to use IntraWeb in Lazarus, so you will likely have to contact AToZed directly about that.
